# dual boot fails Windows after update/upgrade

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, windows-7

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23384999/ 
I use 12.04 and Windows 7(installed second). I updated/upgraded Ubuntu from terminal and lost wireless but found it.But the GNU GRUB version 1.99-21Ubuntu3.19 is not loading Windows. I select Windows and the screen goes black for a second and then goes purple again (returns to grub menu). I checked the partitions, Windows still have the flag:boot. I did update to grub and "Found Windows 7 (loader) on dev/sda3...done". Also, the GRUB menu has 8 options after the upgrade and not 7 like before, the new one is about returning Ubuntu to factory state. Can you please help me boot Windows again?

Comment: In the terminal type sudo update-grub , wait for the update to finish.
Reboot your computer and see if it helps.

Comment: I did that three times and restarted but nothing.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Thank you for the info, this is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23384999/